# Search users based on multiple elements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, search

I am trying to implement search functionality for user records with first_name, last_name, email, project_name,feature_name.

Here first_name, last_name and email is from one table (User), project_name from table Project and feature_name from table Feature.Association of models shown below.

I have a user index page where lists all users from table User. Need a search which search for users which we are entering.

model user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users, dependent: :destroy
end
```

User have fields of first_name, last_name, email etc(using these three fields for search)

model project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :project_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :features, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :project_users, source: :user
end
```

Project have project_name(we search using project name)

model feature.rb

```
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Feature have feature_name(with feature_name we need to search)

**What I am look for**

We have params[:search_member] which contains the searched item(first_name, last_name, email, project_name, feature_name

For ex:

```
params[:search_member] = "John"
params[:search_member] = "Project1"
params[:search_member] = "Feature1"
params[:search_member] = "john@gmail.com"
```

Need a single query which checks the "params[:search_member]" in these three tables(User, Project and Feature) in fields first_name, last_name, email, project_name, and feature_name and return the users of searched value.

Working of associations

```
current_user.projects # will return all projects belongs to current user

project.users # return all users belongs to project

feature.project # return project that feature belongs to
```

and

```
feature.project.users # will return all users of projects
```

```
def search_all
  if params[:search_member].present?
     #need query here
  else
    User.all
  end
end
```

1. If I enter project_name it will return all users of that particular project
2. If I enter first_name, last_name or email return all users of this details
3. If I enter feature name, return all users of project that the feature belongs to

Trying to do in a single joins query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
if params[:search_member].present
  search = params[:search_member]
  User.joins(projects: :features).where('users.first_name ILIKE :search
        OR users.last_name ILIKE :search
        OR users.email ILIKE :search
        OR projects.project_name ILIKE :search
        OR features.name ILIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%").references(:projects).uniq
else
  User.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this

```
def search_all
  if params[:search_member].present?
    User.includes(projects: :features)
        .where(first_name: params[:search_member])
        .or(User.where(last_name: params[:search_member])
        .or(User.where(email: params[:search_member])
        .or(Project.where(project_name: params[:search_member]))
        .or(Feature.where(feature_name: params[:search_member]))
  else
    User.all
  end
end
```

and if that works as expected, then I would refactor the different subqueries to scopes in the models to make is easier to read.

Comment: It is returning just " #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x5c06c> ".
Not able to process more with it.When I try to access data from it with a loop or .first or .last(anything) it will raising error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "projects"
LINE 1: ...sers"."last_name" = $2 OR "users"."email" = $3 OR "projects"...

From the logical side the query is correct. Why raising this error? and also for project and feature we want to use find_by, that is also not working

Comment: That it returns a `Relation` is correct, this is how Rails works, it only returns records when you all `each`, `all`, `first`, or something like that on the Relation object. The error message seems to complain about a missing or invalid column name. Hard to tell, can you please copy'n'paste the full error message from the log file?

Comment: I set this query in users and error raised for users.first:

Started GET "/api/v1/members?search_member=progresstrackerdeveloper1" for ::1 at 2023-01-24 17:10:50 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::MembersController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"search_member"=>"progresstrackerdeveloper1"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mOrganisation Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2

Comment: [0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `current_user_organisation'
  [1m[36mNotification Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."recipient_type" = $1 AND "notifications"."recipient_id" = $2 AND "notifications"."read_at" IS NOT NULL ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $3[0m  [["recipient_type", "User"], ["recipient_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:31:in `set_notifications'

Comment: [1m[36mRole Count (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'organisation_manager') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'business_admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'client') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))[0m  [["user_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/policies/user_policy.rb:26:in

Comment: organisation_manager_access_or_business_admin_access_or_client_access?'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 82ms (ActiveRecord: 15.5ms | Allocations: 38110)


  
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "projects"
LINE 1: ...sers"."last_name" = $2 OR "users"."email" = $3 OR "projects"...
                                                             ^
):
  
app/controllers/concerns/multi_search_member.rb:55:in `search_all_data'
app/controllers/api/v1/members_controller.rb:17:in `index'

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to help any further, because the `...` in your last error message `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "projects" LINE 1: ...sers"."last_name" = $2 OR "users"."email" = $3 OR "projects"... ^ )` are exactly masking the table and column names that seem to be missing. Is the column on `projects` really called `project_name`? Or just `name`? Same for the one on `features`?

Comment: There was a change in feature_name, it was "name", but it return same errors. 
Is it is possible to write this with a join query

Comment: Sure, you can just replace the `includes` with `joins`. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem (better quality, cleaner code) and then it can be like that:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :features, through: :projects

  pg_search_scope :search_member,
    against: [:first_name, :last_name, :email],
    associated_against: {
      projects: :name,
      features: :name
    }
end
```

And then:

```rb
def search_all
  if params[:search_member].present?
     User.search_member(params[:search_member])
  else
    User.all
  end
end
```